# htaccess - prevent directory access directly but allow directory access from website

Tags: .htaccess

I want to make so no one can access particular directory or files directly from browser. But I want to make so above prevented directory and files are accessible through website.

Using below code, I can prevent direct access of 'data' folder from browser. But when I checked from website, all content that is coming from 'data' folder are not displaying (means not accessible).

```
RewriteRule ^(data/) - [F,L,NC]
```

Using below code, I can prevent direct access of below mentioned extensions files from browser. But when I checked from website, all content with these extensions are not displaying (means not accessible).

```
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|wmv)$ - [F]
```

What changes should I make in .htaccess to make it possible?

Comment: It's not possible. Some sites block direct linking by checking the `referer` header, but it's trivial to get around that. Also some people disable this header in their browser. These people wouldn't be able to see your site. If you still want to do this, search for htaccess referer (first result: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-referrer/), and if you decide you want to go this way, maybe edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: @sneep, thank you for your reply. I don't want to block traffic from specific domains so referrer may not work for me. is it possible to do using PHP? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?yoursite\.com/ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F]
```

The problem right now , when someone exploring the page that has one of these files and open the source code , he will be able to browse that file directly from cache unless reloading the page , so if you want to prevent that as well , you could disable cache for specific mentioned extensions but ***you must know what that means prior to disable caching them .***